# What is the radiation level at the L2 Mars-Sun point?

Tags: radiation, lagrangian-points

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/is-the-l2-mars-sun-point-protected-from-solar-radiation) shows that the radiation levels at the L2 Mars-Sun point will be lower because it lies within Mars' solar umbra. So what will the level of radiation be at the L2 Mars-Sun point?
Also, how will the CME's affect a satellite present here? 
It would be helpful if someone could also provide the calculations.